# Easy geometric sum with binomial coefficient

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, summation, binomial-coefficients

In the context of stochastic processes I came across the following equality, where $|s| < 1, p \in [0,1]$:
$$\sum^\infty_{k=0}(s^2p(1-p))^k\begin{pmatrix}
2k \\ 
k
\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4s^2p(1-p)}}$$

This should be true using elementary analysis methods, but I don't know how to deal with the binomial coefficient. The furthest that I can get is that
$$\sum^\infty_{k=0}(s^2p(1-p))^k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-s^2p(1-p)}}$$

Comment: That's just the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem) for $(1+x)^{-1/2}$

Comment: @GrigoryM I still can't actually see it, would you mind writing it out explicitly?

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient.

Comment: @joriki Perfect, just what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from [joriki's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774637/easy-geometric-sum-with-binomial-coefficient#comment3621929_1774637), we note that $\begin{pmatrix}
2k \\ 
k
\end{pmatrix}$ has generating function $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$.